# C# implements interface and extends generic class

Tags: c#

I want to create class as follows:

```
public class ClassB<T> : IInterface1, ClassA<T> where T : IInterface2
```

But IDE is returning me error because base class must come before any interfaces and giving IInterface1 at the end would connect it with T. What can I do with this?

Comment: Put the `where` constraint after the list of inherited types.

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message represents the reason. The class must come before any interface. Just reverse the order.

```
public interface IInterface1 { }

public interface IInterface2 { }

public class ClassA<T> { T obj; }

public class ClassB<T> : ClassA<T>, IInterface1 where T : IInterface2 { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first specify **base class** *then* interface like so:

```
public class ClassB<T> : ClassA<T>, 
                         IInterface1 
    where T : IInterface2
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Just browsing and I cam accross this......Could you possibly give an explaination of what goes on here.  I mean specifically the where T : Interface2 bit.

Comment: We write generic class, where T generic parameter of class, where T : IInterface2 we set up restriction of parameter  we can pass,  that means our class can works only with types which implements Interface2